# How to install Windows game on Ubuntu Steam from standalone installer?

Tags: 20.04, games, steam

I have a standalone installer for the game "Osmos", `OsmosInstaller_1.6.0.exe` that is meant to be run on Windows. I would like to play the game on Ubuntu 20.04 through Steam, but I am not sure how to do it.

I tried adding the installer to my Steam library through the "Add a Game" dialog, but when I click "Play" nothing happens.

I also tried extracting the contents of the installer with Archive Manager, and adding the extracted `Osmos.exe` to Steam in the same way, but clicking "Play" still doesn't do anything.

**Edit:**

I realized that I forgot to force the use of Proton. I was able to run the installer in Steam. The installer then asked if I wanted to run the game and it ran. I am not sure how to run the game again though. I found the installed files in my

`.steam/debian-installation/steamapps/compatdata/2621714962/pfx/drive_c/Program Files (x86)`

But adding the .exe to Steam in the way mentioned above produces the same results.

Answer (score 3):

I almost had it!

[This page](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/ahpbmr/how_to_install_any_windows_exe_with_steam_guild/) shows how to do what I want. I will summarize it here:

1. Add the installer to your Steam library with "Add a non-Steam to My Library"
2. Right click on the installer in your library and force the use of Proton
3. Click on the installer in your library and then click "Play". The installer should run.
4. Search your .steam folder for the game .exe
5. Open properties for the installer, and change the target to the .exe you found